# php - agrupar array y sumar atributos iguales

Tags: php, array

necesito agrupar un array en un formato en específico y no lo consigo hacer, que se agrupe por id y los nombres queden como atributo con el valor del importe sumándose en caso de repetir, les comparto el array original, y mas abajo como necesito dejarlo.

```
$arrayOriginal = array(
  array(
    "id" => 49,
    "nombre" => "DEPORTE",
    "importe" => 40000
  ),

  array(
    "id" => 49,
    "nombre" => "DEPORTE",
    "importe" => 10000
  ),

  array(
    "id" => 49,
    "nombre" => "SOLIDARIDAD",
    "importe" => 40000
  ),

  array(
    "id" => 50,
    "nombre" => "APORTE",
    "importe" => 30000
  ),

  array(
    "id" => 50,
    "nombre" => "APORTE",
    "importe" => 40000
  ),

  array(
    "id" => 50,
    "nombre" => "SOLIDARIDAD",
    "importe" => 20000
  ),
);
```

Dejarlo de la siguiente manera, si no tiene un atributo del nombre que quede en cero.

```
[
  {
    "id": 49,
    "APORTE": 0,
    "DEPORTE": 50000,
    "SOLIDARIDAD": 40000
  },
  {
    "id": 50,
    "APORTE": 70000,
    "DEPORTE": 0,
    "SOLIDARIDAD": 20000
  }
]
```

si me pueden ayudar por favor, le dejo lo que ya intente hacer (no se supe poner los montos y que se sumen)

```
$arrayResult = array();

foreach ($arrayOriginal as $t) {
  $repeat = false;
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayResult); $i++) {
    if ($arrayResult[$i]['id'] == $t['id']) {
      $arrayResult[$i]['id'] = $t['id'];
      $arrayResult[$i]['APORTE'] = '';
      $arrayResult[$i]['DEPORTE'] = '';
      $arrayResult[$i]['SOLIDARIDAD'] = '';
      $repeat = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ($repeat == false)
    $arrayResult[] = array('id' => $t['id'], 'APORTE' => '', 'DEPORTE' => '', 'SOLIDARIDAD' => '');
}

return $arrayResult;
```

Comment: Hola David, deberías mostrar que has intentado, de esa forma tu pregunta será mejor recibida!!

Comment: @MarcePuente gracias, ya lo modifique

Comment: En tu ejemplo de salida no sumas los valores, es así?

Comment: @Yussef si se repite debe sumar, si no queda con el valor que tiene, y si no tiene esa propiedad queda en 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que entendí de tu código es que vas evaluando si está repetido, usando una bandera y un segundo `for`

Creo que lo más fácil es ocupar un diccionario y al final quitar las claves y quedarse con lo valores.

```
$result=[];
foreach($arrayOriginal as $item){
    if (!$result[ $item["id"]] ){
        $result[$item["id"]] = new stdClass();
        $result[$item["id"]]->id=$item["id"];
        $result[$item["id"]]->APORTE=0;
        $result[$item["id"]]->DEPORTE=0;
        $result[$item["id"]]->SOLIDARIDAD=0;
    }
    $a=$item["nombre"];
    $result[$item["id"]]->$a += $item["importe"];
}

$result = array_values($result); //quitamos los indices y nos quedamos con los valores
```

Comment: en la parte `if (!$result[$item["id"]]) {` me da un error **Undefined array key**, como se puede solucionar esa parte por favor.

Comment: dejando así el if ya me funciona `if (!isset($result[$item["id"]])) {` muchas gracias por su ayuda